# Is there a GStreamer filter that does normalization on an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, gstreamer, normalization, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to create a `GStreamer` pipeline that can do image processing.  Specifically, I'm doing image pre-processing to be used by machine learning networks.  So this pipeline will do all the necessary pre-processing steps before it is fed to the neural network.
Right now, I'm trying to figure out if there are any `GStreamer` plugins that can simply do normalization.
GStreamer does allow programmers to create custom plugins for applications.  This is one solution to this question, but I want to find out if there are any pre-existing solutions.

Anything might help!!! Thank you in advance.

I've looked into `GStreamers` list of plugins on their website but there are a lot and some descriptions aren't clear, to me, what they do or how to use them.
This [page](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins_doc.html?gi-language=python) is a list of `GStreamers` plugins provided on their website.

This [plugin](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frei0r/frei0r-mixer-divide.html?gi-language=c) sounded promising but isn't quite what I was looking for.

If anyone is curious, this is the normalization method that I want to replicate for my GStreamer pipeline.

```py
def preprocess(img_data):
    mean_vec = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    stddev_vec = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    norm_img_data = np.zeros(img_data.shape).astype('float32')
    for i in range(img_data.shape[0]):  
         # for each pixel in each channel, divide the value by 255 to get value between [0, 1] and then normalize
        norm_img_data[i,:,:] = (img_data[i,:,:]/255 - mean_vec[i]) / stddev_vec[i]
    return norm_img_data
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use normalization on images for neural network inferences, we usually do:

```
${some video/x-raw stream} ! tensor_converter ! tensor_transform mode=arithmetic option=typecast:float32,add:-127.5,div:127.6 ! tensor_filter ${whatever neural network mode you want} ! ....
```

- GStreamer plugins for neural network processing:
  https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer
- Example code:
  https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer-example
- The code that does normalization like that: https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer-example/blob/master/android/example_app/nnstreamer-multi/jni/nnstreamer-ex.cpp
- The binary of this "example app": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freedesktop.gstreamer.nnstreamer&hl=en